# struts 2 dojo, can't load partial div tag?

Tags: dojo, struts2

Can anyone help me? I can't load div tag partially!
The flow, I run is like that:

When I click submit btn, it call imporUrl and go to action "import" and then call the importAction in ActionBean. 
After that set 'AAA' and 'BBB' to the List. 
Finally it is all working , but it reload the whole form, not only div, I want to reload only div partially. Please help thank !

```
<s:url id="importUrl" action="import">
<s:param name="id" value="%{id}" />
</s:url>

<sx:submit href="%{importUrl}" value="Import" targets="selectedDiv" />

String importAction(){
List.add("AAA");
List.add("BBB");
    return SUCCESS;
}

<s:div id="selectedDiv">
<s:iterator value="List">
    <s:property/>
</s:iterator>
</s:div>
```

Comment: Do you have the `<sx:head>` tag included? Also, you seem to not be accepting any answers and have been reminded of this before--that will make people much, much less likely to help you.

Comment: Surely, I used <sx:head> tag.

Comment: If you put a minimal failing example on github/elsewhere I'll take a look. What specific version of S2 are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think you directly load the div on same page.But you have to do like this.

```
<sx:submit href="%{importUrl}" value="Import" targets="selectedDiv"  
 onclick="javascript:show_details();return false;"/>

And put javascript

<script>
        function show_details() {
            dojo.event.topic.publish("show_detail");
        }
</script>

And make ur div tag like :

<sx:div id="details" listenTopics="show_detail" formId="frm_demo" showLoadingText=""> 
</sx:div>
```